# I got an error when i try to run an Example of React Native Scan QR Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, qr-code

I just want to do an example of React Native Scan QR Code, so I run this command first : "npm install react-native-camera-kit --save".

But i got an error:
'requireNativeComponent: "CameraView" was not found in the UIManager'

I use Expo to execute the app on a device Android version 5.1

That's my component:

```
class QrCodeScreenextends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      qrvalue: '',
      opneScanner: false,
    };
  }
 onOpenlink() {
    //Function to open URL, If scanned 
    Linking.openURL(this.state.qrvalue);
    //Linking used to open the URL in any browser that you have installed
  }
  onBarcodeScan(qrvalue) {
    //called after te successful scanning of QRCode/Barcode
    this.setState({ qrvalue: qrvalue });
    this.setState({ opneScanner: false });
  }
  onOpneScanner() {
    var that =this;
    if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
      async function requestCameraPermission() {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,{
              'title': 'CameraExample App Camera Permission',
              'message': 'CameraExample App needs access to your camera '
            }
          )
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            that.setState({ qrvalue: '' });
            that.setState({ opneScanner: true });
          } else {
            alert("CAMERA permission denied");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Camera permission err",err);
          console.warn(err);
        }
      }
//Calling the camera permission function
      requestCameraPermission();
    }else{
      that.setState({ qrvalue: '' });
      that.setState({ opneScanner: true });
    }    
  }
  render() {
    let displayModal;
    if (!this.state.opneScanner) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>React Native QR Code Example</Text>
            <Text style={styles.simpleText}>{this.state.qrvalue ? 'Scanned QR Code: '+this.state.qrvalue : ''}</Text>
            {this.state.qrvalue.includes("http") ? 
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => this.onOpenlink()}
                style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 12 }}>Open Link</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              : null
            }
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => this.onOpneScanner()}
              style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 12 }}>
                Open QR Scanner
                </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <CameraKitCameraScreen
          showFrame={false}
          scanBarcode={true}
          laserColor={'blue'}
          frameColor={'yellow'}
          colorForScannerFrame={'black'}
          onReadCode={event =>
            this.onBarcodeScan(event.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default QrCodeScreen;
```

Am i missing something !?

Comment: Have you link the third party library?

Comment: i know this is now what are you asking for but expo has own qr scanner and you don't need install any module for use that. I have tried once to use and its really effective and easy to use. [BarCodeScanner](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/) have a look if you're looking for a new alternative

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya what do you mean by third party library !

Comment: @CemKocagöz ok i will try that.

Comment: @SoufienJAOUADI Run react-native link command